# Curve Inner Edges of an Mesh (Not the outer edges which I can use bevel on)

Tags: modeling, mesh, bezier-curves

I am quite new to blender and am trying to model a futuristic delta wing spacecraft/plane. I am having trouble creating a cockpit because I couldn't find how to curve edges. Please note I am not looking for how to bevel the edges but curve the side of an object.

---

I want to note that I started by making two curves then converting them to meshes. Then I joined the meshes. And last I connected the vertices. If there is a better way to do what I am doing please tell me.

---

Here are some reference images to help you understand what I am saying and the situation.

[image: The whole model in wireframe]

[image: The piece I am trying to curve in solid]

Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to post more images. I hope you can understand what I am trying to ask. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Imho, you will benefit from learning about some tool: proportional editing, mirror modifiers, and/or lattice modifiers to edit your current spaceship profile, and maybe vertex snapping if you wish to use a curve, converted to mesh and subdivided enough, as "reference" for side profile to be curved... the manual is a good start (eg: https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/transform/transform_control/proportional_edit.html). btw, you could prefer to restart from scratch and find a better path to your final desired shape...

Comment: @m.ardito I already am using the mirror modifier. I will try using proportinal editing as a last resort. I want to see what other people come up with.

Comment: Can you please upload only the cockpit here(http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com) so i can try to curve it :)?

Comment: @xlxs You would help me more if you would actually tell me how you will do it...

Comment: @xlxs but i will do what you said anyways, the whole piece, the cockpit is separate.

Comment: I'm posting an answer

Comment: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1955/ @xlxs

Answer (score -1):

I didnt found a precise answer but you can delete the mirror modifier then delete the vertices that are in the positions (x,y,0) axis (so you should be left with a mesh that contains vertice that are connected,) then apply a screw modifier and change axis to y. then once you have that object you can apply the screw modifier then use knife to cut through in souch a way that it would be useful to add the mirror modifier again , apply the cut.Then enable clipping in the mirror modifier and scale at x axis to get a pleasing result.Also at this point instead of scaling you can play around with the curve modifier or others modifiers like deform.If you are good in nodes you can install a plugin called sverchok and try creating the cockpit there but it can be ways harder than doing it with this way.

Comment: I don't consider this an acceptable answer. If you have a clear answer then post it, but don't just ramble on with instructions that are anything but clear.

Answer (score -1):

The subsurf modifier does what I wanted to do. When you have a sharp model, try converting it into round by using the sub-surf modifier although it may shrink your model like it did to mine. I hope this helps others.

[image]